# Rails 5.2 Active Storage not deleting attached images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to delete an image that's attached to a job post. But after clicking on remove, the attached image is still there and doesn't get deleted from the job post.

Job Show page

```
<div class="ui text container slides">
        <i class=" left angle icon"></i>
        <i class=" right angle icon"></i>
       <% @job.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
        <div class="slide active">
          <%= image_tag image, size: 200 %> 
 <%= link_to 'Remove', delete_image_attachment_job_url(image.signed_id),
                    method: :delete,
                    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                </div> 
         <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

routes

```
  resources :jobs do
  member do
    delete :delete_image_attachment
  end
end
```

jobs_controller.rb

```
def delete_image_attachment
    @image = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(params[:id])
    @image.purge
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: Please add controller trace to question.

Comment: What exactly you see in application console when submitting an delete action?

Comment: @cnnr doesn't mention anything in particular, just shows that Active_Storage processed the image and no mention of it being deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my controller, i replaced `@image = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(params[:id])`  with:

```
def delete_image_attachment
    @image = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
    @image.purge
    redirect_back(fallback_location: job_path) 
end
```

My delete action is now:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', delete_image_attachment_job_url(image),
                method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```